# How to set timeout to an EJB-Method (in stateless bean)

Tags: hibernate, timeout, ejb, wildfly

I have a stateless session bean and one method needs 6 minutes to return the result, due to that I got the "timeout" exception. I noticed that the timeout was already set in wildfly standalone.xml or in persistence.xml

```
<session-bean>
   <stateful default-access-timeout="12000" cache-ref="simple" passivation-disabled-cache-ref="simple"/>
   <singleton default-access-timeout="12000"/>
</session-bean>
```

or

```
<property name="javax.persistence.query.timeout" value="120000" />
```

but it is only for stateful beans. How can I set the timeout to one method in the stateless bean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with the following annotation and it seems to work:

```
    @AccessTimeout(value = 15, unit = TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    @Override
    public void myMethod() {
        //do something
    }
```

Comment: That sounds pretty surprising. The Javadoc states "This annotation may be applied to a **stateful session bean** or to a **singleton session bean** that uses container managed concurrency. By default, clients are allowed to make concurrent calls to a stateful session object and the container is required to serialize such concurrent requests. The AccessTimeout annotation is used to specify the amount of time a stateful session bean request should block in the case that the bean instance is already processing a different request."

Comment: This answer seems to be wrong. @AccessTimeout is about the waiting time because methods of a stateful bean are synchronized by default. https://openejb.apache.org/examples-trunk/access-timeout/